# convert jquery code to php days counting with two dates

Tags: php, jquery, date, compare

I'm having problem with 2 dates to compare i have 2018-02-01 12:55 and 2018 - 02 -03 12:56 it should give 3 days using this code

```
var startDay = new Date(firstDate);
var endDay = new Date(secondDate);
if (startDay<endDay)
{
    var millisecondsPerDay = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
    var millisBetween = startDay.getTime() - endDay.getTime();
    var days = millisBetween / millisecondsPerDay;
}
```

Comment: What does this have to do with PHP?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking exactly, but perhaps you are looking for `Math.ceil()` to round-up a number?

Comment: when i used it to count number of days it gives accurate days based on 24 hours so when i save it to database i have data which is raw like  2018-02-01 12:55 and 2018 - 02 -03 12:56 so i want to count the number of days based on same result given by the jquery code

Comment: OP may want this JS code in PHP syntax

Comment: the date is like this 2018-03-07 04:46:00 and i want to know if it's possible to convert the code above to php because it gives me the right days

Comment: To enable us to help you, please provide *"the shortest code necessary to reproduce"* the problem that you have with this code in PHP. We can help you with specific problems, not with an unwillingness to learn a language.

Comment: @DrianDrian So, you're wanting us to do it for you? That's not how SO works. If you want help, make an attempt first, then come back with where you got stuck, or seeing errors.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that might work for you.
Use `Date.parse(firstDate)` to convert your date strings to a date. But the problem is the spaces in your second date between the dashes. It would be ideal if you can remove those spaces, but for now I will just use the `replace` function to remove them. Then calculate the time between with endDay - startDay, convert it to days, and use `Math.ceil()` to round up, so if you have 2.000001 days, round it to 3 days.

```
secondDate = secondDate.replace(" - ", "-");
secondDate = secondDate.replace(" -", "-");

var startDay = Date.parse(firstDate);
var endDay = Date.parse(secondDate);

if (startDay<endDay){
    var millisecondsPerDay = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
    var millisBetween = endDay - startDay;
    var days = Math.ceil(millisBetween / millisecondsPerDay);
}
```

PHP EDIT:

```
<?php
/*Set date strings*/
$dateThen = '2018-02-01 12:55';
$dateNow = '2018 - 02 -03 12:56';

/*Fix spacing in date string*/
$dateNow = str_replace(" - ","-",$dateNow);
$dateNow = str_replace(" -","-",$dateNow);

/*Convert date strings to time stamps (seconds)*/
$timestampThen = strtotime($dateThen);
$timestampNow = strtotime($dateNow);
$secondsPerDay =  60 * 60 * 24; //Using seconds, not milliseconds

/*echo Day difference rounded up to nearest whole numper*/
echo ceil(($timestampNow - $timestampThen)/$secondsPerDay);
```